# how to use tooltip on combo-box events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I just want to show example like tooltip while entering data through combo-box for society wings.

I want to show it at the time it got focused

```
    private void cbAddWing_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
        t.Show("for Example.. A,B,C,D..etc", cbAddWing, 1000);
    }

    private void cbAddWing_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
        t.Show("for Example.. A,B,C,D..etc", cbAddWing, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ToolTip way:

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();

void ShowComboBox_ToolTip()
{
    Rectangle screenRectangle = RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);
    int titleHeight = screenRectangle.Top - this.Top;

    Point p = cbAddWing.Location;
    p.X += screenRectangle.Left - this.Left;
    p.Y += titleHeight + cbAddWing.Height;
    p.Y += 5;                           // ToolTip is display below Combobox 5px

    string str = "String " + Environment.TickCount;

    IWin32Window win = this;
    tt.Show(
        str,                            // ToolTip string
        win,                            // Your window
        p,                              // Position
        5000                            // Duration in miliseconds
        );
}

private void cbAddWing_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowComboBox_ToolTip();
}

private void cbAddWing_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowComboBox_ToolTip();
}
```

**Edit:**

If what you want is show an auto suggest list to combobox, you can use `AutoCompleteMode` and `AutoCompleteSource`

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you want to do, but AutoCompleteMode and AutoCompleteSource the combobox class can help you?